# Jquery Chosen Multiselect MVC 5 is not populating selected values on Edit form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my view model:

```
public class AccEditViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Branch")]
    public List<long> Branches { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Type")]
    public string UserType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my action method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById((int)id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        AccEditViewModel model = new AccEditViewModel()
        {                
            Id = user.Id,
            IsActive = user.IsActive,
            UserType = user.UserType,
        };

        model.Branches = new List<long>();

        foreach (Branch branch in user.Branches)
        {
            model.Branches.Add(branch.BranchID);
        }

        ViewBag.Branches = db.Branches.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).AsEnumerable();
        ViewBag.UserTypes = new SelectList(UserTypes.GetUserTypes(), "Value", "Type", user.UserType);

        return View(model);
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Branches, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBox("Branches", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Branches, "BranchID", "Name", Model.Branches.AsEnumerable()), new { @class = "form-control branches-select" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Branches)
    </div>
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/chosen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script> $(".branches-select").chosen(); </script>
```

When I use the `Branches` property which is in the model, it's showing without populated selected values this is a problem and when I use another property which is not decleared in ViewModel then working fine but not with ViewModel property which I need on POST method..

Please tell me what's wrong with this code..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different name for your ViewBag collection than your Model property..

Controller

```
ViewBag.BranchList = db.Branches.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).AsEnumerable();
```

View

```
@Html.ListBox("Branches", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.BranchList,"BranchID","Name" ,Model.Branches.AsEnumerable()), new { @class = "form-control branches-select" })
```